# Implementing Different Cell Types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

I need some help figuring out how I can provide each row of a `UITableView` with a custom cell, i.e. first cell has a "Name" title, the second cell has an "Email" title etc.

How can I achieve this using protocols and following MVVM at the same time?

My current solution is as follows:

I have 1 ViewModel, 1 Controller and 1 UITableViewCell atm.

```
struct ProfileNameViewModel
{

}

extension ProfileNameViewModel: TextPresentable
{
    var text: String
    {
        return "Name"
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class ProfileController: UIViewController
{
    // VARIABLES
    let profileView = ProfileView()
    let profileTableView: UITableView =
    {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return tableView
    }()

    private var profileCellViewControllers = [UIViewController]()
    let testVC = UIViewController()

    // FUNCTIONS
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        navigationItem.title = "Profile"

        // profileTableView initialization
        setupProfileTableView()
    }

    private func setupProfileTableView()
    {
        profileTableView.delegate = self
        profileTableView.dataSource = self

        profileTableView.register(ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>.reuseIdentifier)

        view.addSubview(profileTableView)

        profileTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        profileTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        profileTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        profileTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    private func setupProfileViewLayout()
    {
        profileView.setupAnchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                                 bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                                 left: view.leftAnchor,
                                 right: view.rightAnchor)
    }
}

extension ProfileController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    // Table view header setup
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return "Profile"
        }

        return "Foo"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 50
    }

    // Table view sections setup
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if (section == 1)
        {
            return 3
        }

        return 5
    }

    // Table view cell setup
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell<ProfileNameViewModel>

        let viewModel = ProfileNameViewModel()
        cell.configure(withDelegate: viewModel)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print(indexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 50
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableViewCell<T>: UITableViewCell where T: TextPresentable
{

    // VARIABLES
    let containerView = UIView()
    var arrowImageView = UIImageView()
    var cellTitle: UILabel!
    var userInformationText: UILabel!

    private var delegate: T?

    // FUNCTIONS
    func configure(withDelegate viewModel: T)
    {
        // Setup relavant views
        cellTitle = UILabel()
        userInformationText = UILabel()
        arrowImageView = setupImageView(imageName: "testImage", contentMode: .scaleAspectFit, imageTintColor: .black)
        setupContainer()

        delegate = viewModel

        cellTitle?.text = viewModel.text
        cellTitle.font = viewModel.textFont
        cellTitle.textColor = viewModel.textColor

        userInformationText.text = "Test"
    }

    private func setupContainer()
    {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(cellTitle)
        containerView.addSubview(userInformationText)
        containerView.addSubview(arrowImageView)

        // Container view for each cell
        containerView.setupAnchors(top: topAnchor,
                               bottom: bottomAnchor,
                               left: leftAnchor,
                               right: rightAnchor,
                               padding: .init(top: 3, left: 0, bottom: 3, right: 0))

        // Views inside the container view
        cellTitle.setupAnchors(top: nil,
                           bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor,
                           left: containerView.leftAnchor,
                           right: nil,
                           padding: .init(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 7, right: 0))

        arrowImageView.setupAnchors(top: nil,
                                bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor,
                                left: nil,
                                right: containerView.rightAnchor,
                                padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 13, right: 5),
                                size: .init(width: 10, height: 10))

        userInformationText.setupAnchors(top: nil,
                                     bottom: containerView.bottomAnchor,
                                     left: nil,
                                     right: arrowImageView.leftAnchor,
                                     padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 7, right: 10))
    }

    private func setupImageView(imageName: String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode, imageTintColor: UIColor) -> UIImageView
    {
        let arrowImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
        let arrowImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: arrowImage)
        arrowImageView.contentMode = contentMode
        arrowImageView.imageTintColor(color: imageTintColor)

        return arrowImageView
    }
}
```

I was trying to follow the example provided by [this](https://www.natashatherobot.com/updated-protocol-oriented-mvvm-in-swift-2-0/) link to implement a proper solution, however, only one cell is added and I can't wrap my head around how to implement a second cell at following rows. Am I supposed to create a new ViewModel for each separate cell that I would like to use? If that is the case, could you please provide an example?

Comment: May I recommend that you edit the code to a clearer example?  There are missing part that that make your code not compile and, at the same time, are not that relevant for the question.  Boil it down to something simpler that compiles.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. Give me some time and I’ll edit the code to a working example.

Comment: Cool I really think that you are asking an important question. The problem you face is a recurring one in the iOS community and it is possible to make table views that take generic cells, expressively put together. If you see my answer there is an example that suggests a way of doing it. And it's not an issue strictly connected with MVVM as an architecture, it's more general.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a "box" to contain your cell generation code.  Don't register cell id before the cell is needed.  It's a bit difficult to come up with a working example so please take the following code as an example:

```
import UIKit

protocol CellBox {

    func getCell(for tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell
}

struct MyCellBox: CellBox {

    private let id = "my_cell_id"

    func getCell(for tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id) {
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: id)
        }
    }
}

class MyDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var boxes: [CellBox] = []
    // This is just a hack for compiling...
    // ...the idea is that you need to have a reference to your real table view somewhere
    let tableView = UITableView()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return boxes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        return boxes[indexPath.row].getCell(for: tableView)
    }
}
```

I do recommend that you shrink the question to a more manageable example, however as an improvement to the above `MyCellBox`, there is a chance that this is close to what you want:

```
struct MyCellBox: CellBox {

    private let id = "my_cell_id"

    func getCell(for tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id) {
            return cell
        } else {
            let viewModel = MyViewModel(text: "WOW", font: UIFont(name: "Whatever", size: 10)!, color: UIColor.black)
            let cell = ProfileTableViewCell<MyViewModel>()
            cell.configure(withDelegate: viewModel)
            return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: id)
        }
    }
}
```